# get_the_term_list without links in 3.1

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, terms

What function will display custom taxonomies associated with a post as text?

I'm currently using get_the_term_list which works great for a singular page but not so much when using a taxonomy in the archive-postype.php permalink title tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

wp_get_object_terms() returns the terms associated with an object (eg a post or a page or custom post) as text (normally in an array).

From [the Codex page for wp_get_object_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

`$productcategories = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'productcategories');`

Comment: Keep in mind that the query results aren't cached like `get_the_terms()`. See the [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) for info.

Answer (score 24):

However [@anu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/get-the-term-list-without-links-in-3-1/8291#8291) is right, I figured out you can call the php function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to strip out the tags of the return value.

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'tags' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
```

Comment: Looks so simple and does the job. Is there any downside using this?

Comment: @Mohsin One downside is that it strips all tags, not just the <a> tag. However, you can prevent desired tags from being stripped, like so: `$terms = strip_tags( $terms, '<li>' );`

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to implement a filter for the term list, that extract via regexp only the text, from the list

See [`get_the_terms_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/) and the Hook in [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_links-taxonomy/).

```php
 $term_links = apply_filters( "term_links-{$taxonomy}", string[] $links )
```

You can implement your own filter.

Comment: That's exactly the hook I found by reading the source code.

Answer (score 3):

```
$terms = wp_list_pluck( get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your_taxonomy' ), 'name');
```

Here $terms is an array, so you can use a foreach loop.

```
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
  echo $term;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I need the same and tried Zack solution that works great. For instance, if you need onlye the term to put in css id or class.
Only one anotation about the solution, the function is bad called, properly is "get_the_term_list".

I show my example:

```
$terms = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'your_taxonomy_name' );
$terms = strip_tags( $terms );
```