# List custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am trying to display all of the terms for a custom taxonomy(`characters`), the taxonomy is related to a custom post type(`books`).

What I would like to do is display all of the terms for `characters`, so say for instance I have two `books`, and I add three `characters` to each `book`, I would like all six characters to display.

I would only like to get the names, not links, or in list form, if I could get a set of objects or an array that would be preferable.

Thank you.

Comment: Please check the link bellow: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8291/68186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function. I found it looking at the code for [wp_tag_cloud](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2/wp-includes/category-template.php#L526), here is the [source of the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1149). This little snippet should get you what you are wanting.

```
$terms = get_terms("characters");

if ( empty( $tags ) || is_wp_error( $tags ) )
  return;

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: rtgibbons, when trying to use this, it breaks my site.

Comment: Not sure way, make sure the get_terms is getting the term of your taxonomy. If are, then open up another question, feel free to send me the link when you on twitter @rtgibbons

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to your functions.php and pass 'characters' as an argument (or the slug for your custom taxonomy) to show a comma separated list of all your terms.

```
function show_all_terms($taxonomy){
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    foreach($taxonomy_terms as $term){
        $terms[] = $term->name;
    }
    if(!empty($terms)) {
        echo join(", ", $terms);
    }
    else{
        echo "No ".$taxonomy."associated with this ".get_post_type();
    }
}
```

Now you can call this function in your templates like this:

```
show_all_terms('character'); 
// you can replace 'character' with the slug of any custom taxonomy as well.
```